# How to use firebase App Check in a react.js web application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, recaptcha, firebase-app-check

So far I have declared the constant appCheck, as explained in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/app-check). It looks like this:

```
const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {
  provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(siteKey // the recaptcha site key provided by google),
  isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
});
```

Moreover, I have enforced app check in the console for Firestore interaction. Whenever I am trying to interact with my Firestore database, I get rejected (permission not granted) and I can see in the console that I have 100% unverified requests. This indicates that the setup is working.

I can't really figure out how to complete the next step however, and wonder how I would enable verified Firestore interaction. How would I do that?

Comment: I've tried to give a detailed explanation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72879527/implementing-firebase-appcheck-for-react-web/74322825#74322825

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a struggle to set it up. They have very detailed documentation but are lacking real-world examples with pictures or videos step by step.

I've tried to explain in detail how I managed to set it up here for both production and development environments as an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72879527/implementing-firebase-appcheck-for-react-web/74322825#74322825).

- [Firebase set up app check docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-provider)
- [Firebase set up app check - debugging docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/debug-provider)
- [reCAPTCHA V3 docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3)